# How to readline() of a previous sentence

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to capture data from a log file. 
However, I would like to first check whether the test is passed and then only capture the success tests that ran. 
In the log file, the indicator about whether the test has passed is after the total passed test number.

```
PASS 4 Tests Ran, 0 Tests Failed
Execution time (mm:ss): 6: 3 
PASSED
```

I need to first check whether "PASSED: is present and then move up 3 lines above to obtain the number of passed ran tests which is 4.

I've used a loop to read each line first to check whether the word "PASSED" is present

```
while True:
Line=a.readline()
Line=Line.strip('\n')
if re.search (r'PASSED', Line) is not None:
```

I need to jump up to get the passed number... Any ideas how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the last two lines (in `prev_line` and `prev_prev_line`), and use `prev_prev_line` to get the number of passed tests.

```py
prev_prev_line = ''
prev_line = ''

while True:
    prev_prev_line = prev_line
    prev_line = Line
    Line=a.readline()
    Line=Line.strip('\n')
    if re.search (r'PASSED', Line) is not None:
        get_number_of_passed_tests(prev_prev_line)
```